# In Next JS, changes in layout.tsx only applies to home page, other pages are not affected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes

**UPDATE**

My answer is not working: Next JS 13 does not recommend adding `_app.tsx` or `_document.tsx`, instead, we should use the default `layout.tsx`.

With my solution, Navbar and Footer are added to all pages but there is a console error:
`Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted`
which requires the `html` and `body` tags in `layout.tsx`. However, if I change `layout.tsx` back to it's default, the previously added `_document.tsx` adds an extra `html` tag to the page HTML, causing the following error:
`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.` 
`Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <html> in <div>.`

I'm still looking for a solution.

I have a Next JS app, the version is 13.5.4, its structured like this:

```
- pages
-- about.tsx
- src
-- app
--- layout.tsx
--- page.tsx
```

In order to not repeat code, I changed the default layout.tsx to this:

```
import './globals.scss'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import {Navbar} from "@/app/components/Navbar/navbar";
import {Footer} from "@/app/components/Footer/footer";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar /> // ---- added this
          {children}
        <Footer /> // ---- added this
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My goal is to have Navbar and Footer on every page by default. Now the problem is, they are on homepage, i.e. applied to page.tsx. But they are not on /about. Any idea why?

Here is the navbar.tsx which routes to the /about.

```
import Link from "next/link";
export const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/#">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: The app and page router are different things and are treated differently https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have Next JS version 13.5.4, I shouldn't need to migrate?

Comment: You already are migrating?

Comment: you have to pick one and stick to it. vercel has separated documents for page folder structure and app folder structure. i might be wrong, but you cannot use page and app folder structure together.

Comment: basically if you use page then delete app folder. if you use app then delete page folder.

Comment: @Layhout I don't think so, in my project /pages and /src/app folders co-exist

Comment: @Layhout next allow incremental adoption of the two approaches. They just don't share components or layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution:

The `pages` folder should be empty, everything should be in `/src/app` The correct project layout should be:

```
|-project
|--src
|---app
|----about
|-----page.tsx
|----components
|-----Navbar
|------Navbar.tsx
|-----Footer
|------Footer.tsx
|----globals.scss
|----layout.tsx
|----page.tsx
```

The `layout.tsx` should be:

```
import { Navbar } from "@/app/components/Navbar/navbar";
import { Footer } from "@/app/components/Footer/footer";
import './globals.scss'

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}
export default function RootLayout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 main">
          <Navbar />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Then `src/app/about/page.tsx` should be

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      About me
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then there is no console error, the navbar and footer are on every page without defining in each page `.tsx` file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @evolutionxbox, I found the answer on official doc:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app
here
[image]
The solution is:

1. add a `/pages/_document.tsx` as follows:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

2. add a `/pages/_app.tsx` as follows:

```
import Layout from "@/app/layout";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Then there should be no need to add `import` in the `/src/app/page.tsx` or `/pages/about.tsx`, they should simply be like:

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      About me
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Glad you found an explanation.